# Not able to render children {children} component in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-props, i18next

I'm working with i18n library for translate languages and it works but now i want to upgrade things using my Screen component to make the code more light.
For doing so i crated my screen component :

```
interface Props {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  currentLanguage: string;
  setCurrentLanguage: (newlanguage: string) => void;
  languages: Language[];
  renderNavBar?: () => JSX.Element;
}
export default function Screen({children}: Props) {
  const [currentLanguage, setCurrentLanguage] = useState(i18n.language);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(children);

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(children);
  }, [children]);

  return (
    <View>
      <NavBar
        languages={languageList}
        currentLanguage={currentLanguage}
        setCurrentLanguage={(newLanguage: string) => {
          setCurrentLanguage(newLanguage);
        }}
      />

      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{height: '100%'}}>
        <>{children}</>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

importing a Navbar that contains the language selector component witch do all the work of translation :

```
interface Props {
  hideNavbar?: boolean;
  currentLanguage: string;
  setCurrentLanguage: (newlanguage: string) => void;
  languages: Language[];
}
export default function NavBar({
  hideNavbar,
  currentLanguage,
  setCurrentLanguage,
}: Props) {
  return (
    <View style={appStyles.headerContainer}>
      <Text style={appStyles.titleScreen}>
        TAKE A TOUR OF THE BASILICA OF SANTA MARIA NOVELLA
      </Text>
      <LanguageSelector
        languages={languageList}
        currentSelectedLanguage={currentLanguage}
        onLanguageChanged={(newLanguage: string) => {
          setCurrentLanguage(newLanguage);
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

if helps here is my languageComponent structure :

```
interface Props {
  languages: Language[];
  currentSelectedLanguage: string;
  onLanguageChanged: (newlanguage: string) => void;
}

function LanguageSelector({
  languages,
  onLanguageChanged,
  currentSelectedLanguage,
}: Props) {
  const renderItem = ({item}: {item: Language}) => (
    <Pressable
      onPress={() => {
        changeLanguage(item.value);
        onLanguageChanged(item.value);
      }}
      style={{padding: 10, paddingHorizontal: 50}}>
      <Text
        style={
          currentSelectedLanguage === item.value
            ? {
                color: appColors.orange,
                fontSize: 25,
                marginBottom: 10,
                fontFamily: 'Work Sans SemiBold',
              }
            : {
                color: appColors.white,
                fontSize: 25,
                marginBottom: 10,
                fontFamily: 'Work Sans SemiBold',
              }
        }>
        {item.label}
      </Text>
    </Pressable>
  );

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={languages}
      keyExtractor={item => item.value}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      horizontal
      contentContainerStyle={styles.container}
    />
  );
}
```

right now i want to use Screen in home component to change language of a message as i change the language selected :

HOME SCREEN:

```
return (
    <Screen
      languages={languageList}
      currentLanguage={currentLanguage}
      setCurrentLanguage={(newLanguage: string) => {
        setCurrentLanguage(newLanguage);
      }}>
      <View style={appStyles.flex}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={require('@assets/images/cappella-sistina.jpeg')}
          style={appStyles.imageScreen}>
          <View style={appStyles.homeOverlay}>
            <View style={appStyles.topTabText}>
              <Text style={appStyles.textScreen}>{__(T.messages.welcome)}</Text>
              <Text style={[appStyles.italicText, {color: appColors.white}]}>
                {__(T.messages.interact)}
              </Text>
              <Text style={appStyles.textScreen}>€ 2,00</Text>
            </View>
            <Pressable
              onPress={onSecretButtonCounter}
              style={appStyles.settingsButton}
            />
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>

        {showKeypadModal && (
          <KeypadModal onCancel={onCancel} onConfirm={onConfirmPassword} />
        )}
      </View>
    </Screen>
  );
```

It does work only if i control + s my homeScreen after i click the language i selected.
i want the component change immediately as i change the language,
Please help me i'm crazy about this .

Comment: Based on the code above, the scroll view doesn't have a reason to render when currentLangauge is set. It will only react when children changes.

Comment: Consider adding "currentLangauge" as one of your dependencies in the useEffect. That way both children props and currentLanguage will cause children to be set. Although I'm not sure this would still work. Worth a shot.

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    setValue(currentLanguage);
  }, [currentLanguage]);


like this right?

Comment: didn't work i'm sorry

Comment: No. Like This. useEffect(() => {
    setValue(children);
  }, [children, currentLanguage]);